# using ConfigMap created using Generator in Kustomize/Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, generator, configmap, kustomize

I have been trying to figure out how to consume a ConfigMap created using a ConfigMap generator  via Kustomize.

When created using Kustomize generators, the configMaps are named with a special suffix. See here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap-from-generator

Question is how can this be referenced?

Answer (score 4):

You don't reference it yourself. Kustomize recognizes where the configMap is used in the other resources (like a Deployment) and changes those references to use the name+hash.

The reason for this is so that if you change the configMap, Kustomize generates a new hash and updates the Deployment, causing a rolling restart of the Pods.

If you don't want this behavior, you can add the following to your `kustomization.yaml` file:

```
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true
```

Answer (score 1):

It is specified there in the doc. When you do `kubectl apply -k .` a configmap created named `game-config-4-m9dm2f92bt`.
You can check that the ConfigMap was created like this: `kubectl get configmap`. This ConfigMap will contains a field data where your given datas will belong.

Now as usual you can use this configmap in a pod. Like below:

Ex from k8s:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env:
        # Define the environment variable
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              # The ConfigMap containing the value you want to assign to SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
              name: special-config
              # Specify the key associated with the value
              key: special.how
  restartPolicy: Never
```

You can use ConfigMap as volume also, like this example from k8s doc:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: demo
      image: alpine
      command: ["sleep", "3600"]
      env:
        # Define the environment variable
        - name: PLAYER_INITIAL_LIVES # Notice that the case is different here
                                     # from the key name in the ConfigMap.
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: game-demo           # The ConfigMap this value comes from.
              key: player_initial_lives # The key to fetch.
        - name: UI_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: game-demo
              key: ui_properties_file_name
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config
        mountPath: "/config"
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    # You set volumes at the Pod level, then mount them into containers inside that Pod
    - name: config
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap you want to mount.
        name: game-demo
        # An array of keys from the ConfigMap to create as files
        items:
        - key: "game.properties"
          path: "game.properties"
        - key: "user-interface.properties"
          path: "user-interface.properties
```

You can see k8s official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)

Comment: this did not appear to work. The ConfigMap is named 'game-config-4-m9dm2f92bt'. But you are referencing a 'game-config'.  Are you telling me that your installation found 'game-config-4-m9dm2f92bt' when searching for 'game-config'?

Comment: The question is how is this done programmatically. The code to create uses 'game-config-4'. But 'game-config-4-m9dm2f92bt' gets created. And the code to consume, should also be referencing 'game-config-4', without knowing ahead of time whatever the tag may be added. Is there some qualification that says something like 'game-config-4:latest' or with some time period?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this too. I could not figure out why kustomize was not updating the configmap name for the volume in the deployment to include the hash. What solved this for me was to add `namespace: <namespace>` in the kustomization.yaml for both the base and overlay.

Comment: That was the solution for me, too. I removed `namespace` from all files except from the base `kustomization.file` and it solved the problem. In the base `kustomization.yaml` file, with `configMapGenerator[0].name` set to `my-configmap`, I ended up in my deployment with a translated `configMapKeyRef.name` correctly set to `dev-my-configmap-g75875hhh9` - not erroneously set to `my-configmap`.